# google map to show marker on address

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

js:

```
     function initialize() {
        $('#refreshmap').on('click', initialize);
        var location_latitude = $("#id_location_latitude").val()
        var location_longitude = $("#id_location_longitude").val()
    """"""""""""""
   some code here
    """""""""""""
      $(document).ready(function(){
            function codeAddress() {
            var address = "{{ userprofile.work_street }},{{userprofile.work_suburb}},{{userprofile.work_postcode}},{{ userprofile.work_country }}";
            alert(address);
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
               });
                 } else {
                 alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                 }
               });
              }
              $("#img-clck").click(codeAddress);
           });
         '''''''
        some code
       ''''''''''
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

update:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    function geocodePosition(pos) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: pos
        }, function(responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {

            }
        });
    }
    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
        document.getElementById('id_location_latitude').value = latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('id_location_longitude').value = latLng.lng();
    }

    function initialize() {
        $('#refreshmap').on('click', initialize);
        var location_latitude = $("#id_location_latitude").val()
        var location_longitude = $("#id_location_longitude").val()

        if(location_latitude){
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location_latitude, location_longitude);

        }else{
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.813988, 144.963441);
         }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

       $(document).ready(function(){

        var address = "{{ userprofile.work_street }},{{userprofile.work_suburb}},{{userprofile.work_postcode}},{{ userprofile.work_country }}";
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
           });
             $("#img-clck").hide();
             } 
           });        
       });


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            title: 'Position',
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            visible:false
        });

        updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
        geocodePosition(latLng);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {

            updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        });
        if(location_latitude){
            marker.setVisible(true);
           $("#img-clck").hide();
        }
        $('#img-clck').click(function(){
            marker.setVisible(true);
            $("#img-clck").hide();
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

This is my code to show marker on given address,it is showing the marker on the given address on button click.I want it to happen on page load.The marker should show the given address on page load,without button click.How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the codeAddress function on the click event of the button. Instead you should call the codeAddress function from initialize function which is called onload.

```
function initialize() {
    $('#refreshmap').on('click', initialize);
    var location_latitude = $("#id_location_latitude").val()
    var location_longitude = $("#id_location_longitude").val()
    codeAddress();
```

I am not sure if it will be called when it is declared inside  $(document).ready. You could either move it out as a standalone function or the other alternate would be to just remove it out of the method i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var address = "{{ userprofile.work_street }},{{userprofile.work_suburb}},{{userprofile.work_postcode}},{{ userprofile.work_country }}";
        alert(address);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
           });
             } else {
             alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
             }
           });

          $("#img-clck").click(codeAddress);
       });
```

This way the code will execute directly when $(document).ready is called.

Comment: getting this error in console "Uncaught ReferenceError: codeAddress is not defined "

Comment: I comment codeAddress(); in function initialize() { and tried,it is working.

Comment: I have one issue,after doing this add marker button is not working,if the address is not their,i had set a default latitude and longitude point,so if address is not their if the user click Add marker button it should show the marker in that default position.Can you help me in doing this.

Comment: If you could share the code that you're using for adding the marker I might be able to help you.

Comment: I shared the code what i am using,the old problem i solved. Now the issue is if the marker is at mentioned address,when i click Refresh button more than 3 times,it moves to the default latitude and longitude location what i set in code.Can you check and tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Just now i found that the marker in mentioned address gets disappeared after 2 refreash.I think that be the problem,do you have any idea where could be the issue.

Comment: You have added only the javascript code without the html part so was unable to actually run it and check but I think the reason it moves to the default location is that it is not getting the values of latitude and longitude. 

Try alerting the value in 'id_location_latitude' like this : 

{
    alert($("#id_location_latitude").val() + " , " + $("#id_location_longitude").val());
        var location_latitude = $("#id_location_latitude").val()
        var location_longitude = $("#id_location_longitude").val()
}

Comment: Also take the code to add the onclick listener i.e. the first line in the initialize function outside the initialize function as the listener needs to be attached just once and the initialize function may get called multiple times.